# Is there a truss equivalent for PASE?

Tags: pase

I'm trying to debug a java app running in PASE, and this is the type of problem I'd typically use strace or procmon on for linux and Windows respectively. The AIX equivalent is [truss](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/au-apptracing/).

I don't seem to have truss on my PASe environment and don't see a reference to it anywhere. Is there a different tool for PASE?

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to assume that all AIX commands are supported by PASE; PASE is not AIX, it is a "runtime environment" that allows many AIX applications to run under OS/400 or IBM i.

So, no, there is no "truss" command or "strace" in PASE; you must use the native debugging and tracing features of OS/400 or IBM i.